# NPM rimraf - continue executing when folders are missing (stop exit code 1)

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, command-line, npm

I have an npm script set up to a few synchronous commands. The starting command is `npm run clean:install"`.

Here is the sequence:

`"install:all": "npm install && bower install",
 "clean": "npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc typings coverage wwwroot bower_components"
 "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
 "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm run install:all"`

Works fine if all directories exist. The problem is if any of the directories are already deleted, the script exists with code 1 and prevents all additional syncronous scripts from running.

So that means it failes to run the original command of clean:install which is " `"clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm run install:all`"

Error from npm:

```
npm ERR! angular2-webpack-starter@5.0.4 clean: `npm cache clean && npm run 
rimraf -- node_modules doc typings coverage wwwroot bower_components`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-webpack-starter@5.0.4 clean script 'npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc typings coverage wwwroot bower_components'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-webpack-starter package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc typings coverage wwwroot bower_components
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-webpack-starter
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-webpack-starter
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

The last line gives it away. It wants `node_modules` but can't find it so it fails.

How can I make my script continue executing to ignore these failures (missing directories)?

**EDIT: The error occurs because rimraf is removing `node_modules` and wiping itself out. Once the folder it cleared, rimraf is gone and exit code 1. Can I exclude the rimraf folder within node_modules so it exists correctly?**

Comment: `rimraf` or the executed (`rm -rf` - on *NIX platforms) always exits with code 0, even if folders do not exist. The error you're getting doesn't live within `rimraf` module. You are running `npm cache clean` before `rimraf`, how can you be sure that isn't the issue?

Comment: Good point. Although even if I stick to the basics and just run the rimraf command I get error `>npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc typings coverage wwwroot bower_components`

`> rimraf "node_modules" "doc" "typings" "coverage" "wwwroot" "bower_components"`

`The system cannot find the path specified.`

Comment: I figured out the problem. It's because rimraf is removing itself, since it lives inside node_modules. Once it wipes itself out, script fails code 1. Is there a a way to rimraf and exclude the rimraf directory within node_modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a bit tricky. The problem was because rimraf was removing itself since it was only installed locally in node_modules. So as soon as it removed the node_modules dir, the program died.

I realized it was necessary to add a task to have it install rimraf globally. The first task that executes is `install:all`. Then rimraf is in the global PATH. However, rimraf was a dependency for many other node_modules, **so it kept getting installed locally and therefore ignored the global PATH.** It kept dying because it was still referencing the local node_modules folder.

**The trick was to uninstall rimraf locally right before executing any rimraf command. Now it's forced to use the global PATH because it doesn't exist locally.**

```
"preinstall:all": "npm install typings webpack-dev-server rimraf webpack -g",
"install:all": "npm install && bower install",

"prerimraf": "npm uninstall rimraf",
"rimraf": "rimraf",

"clean": "npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc typings coverage wwwroot bower_components"

"preclean:install": "npm run clean",
"clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm run install:all"
```

After `install:all` has been executed on project load (in Visual Studio 2015, Task Runner Explorer has a binding called `Project Open`), there are times I want to clean everything and start fresh. Now I can simply execute `clean:install` and uninstall node_modules and reinstall immediately with no problem! Exit code 0. Sweet!

Answer (score 4):

I am (probably) looking at this [boilerplate project](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) you're using. Did you read the instructions? They are asking you to run `npm install typings webpack-dev-server rimraf webpack -g`, which includes **installing `rimraf` globally**, before even using the project. If you've failed to do this, using the `npm run clean:install`, or anything which calls this script, will fail because the `rimraf` module can't be found in your local `node_modules` (if already removed) or it will be deleting itself.

Comment: Thanks I just thought of that right as you posted your answer. I need to make it so other devs and just fire the project up without going to command line so i made an npm script which executes the install globally. Although I should add all those to the global install, thanks for letting me know. I'll give you the credit. Yes I am using that angular2-webpack-starter boilerplate and I am integrated it with ASP.net Core 1.0 for visual studio dev environment.